# sphinx over multiple servers and database partitions

Tags: mysql, database, search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

hi i want to create user search fully driven with sphinx. problem is that my data are
spread over multiple servers and databases, whitch, some of them are partitioned. So in
finall i have three data sources, one is table with basic user data and its not
partitioned, second is table on other server whitch store live action of users currently
log in, with some basic information, and third is user profile data, fully partitioned
(16 segments) and on the same server as live users

there is no problem to build three separate indexes ... but i want one search one main
index

my base index on profile data is working very well but since i dont want to separate
search process i want to merge all data from different servers ...

i have tried MVA by defining source type as SOURCE where i could easyly define eg. host,
user, pass but it isnt supported, then i tried to pass some variables to query source
type but with zero effect

then i looked over some merging of indexes together, but havent find any solution to
this. not runquery doesnt support something like that

it looks like my only hope is to retrieve all data and generate xml whitch then a pass to
sphinx, but to my knowledge i lose live index updates as well as delta index updates,
whitch is problem to my ...

is there any way to do this? something that i havent think of? or got wrong?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

for this type ot task use rather [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

Comment: "Use (insert whole other technology here)" is not much of an answer.  If there's a reason Sphinx won't work, mention it.  Otherwise, this looks more like a gratuitous link to elasticsearch than an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There're few options how you can merge data in Sphinx:

1. you can use multiple 'source's in 'index', this is probably you would like to try first
2. you can use Sphinx distributed index (including having different nodes on different servers with automatic results merging by the parent node)
3. you can use indexer `--merge`, but I guess it doesn't make sense in your case